# Capacitor choice for ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, capacitor

My ceiling fan stopped working and, after performing an [analog multimeter test](https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2013/06/how-to-check-capacitor-with-digital.html) of the capacitor, I have a reason to suspect that it is the cause.

[image: 2]

However, I am unable to find a replacement that matches the specs on my current (3 wire, 3.5 uf, 350VAC, 50-60 Hz):

[image]

[The closest I could find](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017G62TF4) is 2 wire, 3.5 uf, 250VAC.

**Q1:** On the side where my current capacitor has two white wires, can I just splice two branches on that one wire of the replacement?

**Q2:** Is 350VAC on the current vs 250VAC on the replacement a disqualifying difference?

Comment: Don't shop for capacitors on Amazon.  Shop at Galco, Grainger, or Mouser, in that order.

Comment: @harper as shopping advice is off topic I don’t think your comment falls within the site guidelines. As a professional electrician with a degree in electronics that purchases components on: e bay, Amazon, granger, Newark, digikey, jameco and many other online sites how do you back up your comment?

Answer (score 0):

I can not answer your technical question about the capacitor (my husband is the master electrician) but the 22 190-M1985 is the code for that capacitor and I found several. It was a 2009 capacitor. Ebay has one for $7.95, the surplus house has them new for $39.95 (it would be a gamble because electrical parts they do not refund as you can blow them if something else is causing the issue.)

The fans of today are much more efficient especially if they have a DC instead of AC motor (per my husband) and what we have in our house.

https://surpius.com/index.php/product/vim-qpc-mea3-capacitor-e144575-190-m1985-190m1985-c22-2-2033190-tp-ao/

Comment: can you actually post your findings because I am not getting any that match the specs?

Comment: Dc motors do not require a capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to can you use a 250v cap with a line voltage of 120v? NO,  you have to think in terms of peak to peak for component selection.

Voltage measurements are in RMS or root means square the peak to peak value is ~2.8 x the rms value 120x2.8=336 so a 350v cap is needed.

Next that 3.5uf cap has 3 leads this normally means 2 capacitors if only 1 value is provided both are the same so your cap has a cap from the red to white and a second cap from the red to the other white, this is a common configuration.

I purchase components on eBay and Amazon all the time but I understand the values and tolerances in many cases I get the exact same brand ,component  value and voltage component as the one I am replacing. I do have an LCR meter to measure components like this and the parts have been within the stated tolerance.

I found several 3+3.5+6 fan caps for under 10$ online  these have a common that would connect where your red wire did and the 3uf on one white the 3.5 on the other white and put some tape on the 6uf one. I have purchased parts like this many times 6.99$ And now the fan works where the exact component was 35-89$ .
The OEM’s in some cases have unique parts that you can only get through them and you have to pay the markup. A slight difference (Micro farids) uf in this case for a motor won’t matter it will work.

Comment: so are you saying that one of the `several 3+3.5+6 fan caps` could work in my case?

Comment: can i use [this](https://www.amazon.com/HQRP-Capacitor-Harbor-Ceiling-Coaster/dp/B01N6O61EE/ref=asc_df_B01N6O61EE/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=343161280953&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=18154219457944572213&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9061285&hvtargid=pla-764737940073&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=70737352722&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=343161280953&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=18154219457944572213&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9061285&hvtargid=pla-764737940073)?

Comment: The link is not working I have tried a few times. But the 3+3.5+6 should work just cap 6 and use the other 2